# Download text from a website to populate a ScrollView?

Tags: iphone

Hi could anyone point me in the direction that I need to be looking for the downloading of text from a website.

For example;

If I wanted to obtain the text from this website: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorum_ipsum

How would I;

1) How would I go about connecting to the website and reading the content?
2) How would I display this content in a scrollView?

Thanks.

Comment: I took a look at, NSURLConnection but I'm not sure if this would work?

Comment: this is a very general question, it would suggest you haven't done much in the way of learning about cocoa touch and iPhone development

Comment: @Herly: try some things. If you get errors, try to fix them. If you're stumped, post code and ask for help on a specific part. SO is not here to write your app for you.

Comment: @PengOne I know you aren't here to write my app, I was hoping people could either point me in the right direction or give me a starting point I don't want people to write it for me because I won't learn anything that way.

Comment: @Herly: Your question is still too vague. **Try something**. Load a web page in a webview. Get that working. Try to read the title of the page. Try specific things, then ask if you cannot get it working. This question is too general.

Comment: you need to learn cocoa touch programming, a great book for that is head first iphone development. it should equip you with a good understanding of app construction and then you can fill the blanks in by looking at google, id also recommend browsing questions on SO, a great way to learn about the usual issues developers hit

Comment: @Matt Yeah I did a book on Iphone programming about 4 or so months ago but then swapped to Android, all the stuff that I learnt is slowly coming back, walk before you can run huh.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two places to look to get you started:

1. http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html
2. [Is it possible to read the contents of a web page into a string so i can parse out the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330874/is-it-possible-to-read-the-contents-of-a-web-page-into-a-string-so-i-can-parse-ou)

It took 3 seconds and 5 words in a google search to find them.

Comment: @Herly: No you're not dumb, you just need to learn to use the resources available.  :)

Answer (score 0):

To display you could use either UILabel with UIScrollView or UITextView (which has automatic scrolling).

Comment: I took a look at all three of those, and I think that the UITextView is the best for me because of the auto-scroll.